# Does the "max vCPU" limit only apply to the "CPU" wait state?

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, aws-aurora

[image]

In the *Average Active Sessions* chart of *Performance Insights* for Aurora MySQL 8, there is a horizontal *Max vCPU* (at 16, in my case). Now I wonder if this limit applies only to the *CPU* wait state (green in the example chart), or to all other wait states as well (as they are all in the same vertical dimension, crossing the *Max vCPU* line).

In my example, the CPU is always well below the maximum, so would reducing the wait/io/redo_log_flush - often the highest wait state value by far - of one SQL statement speed up the execution of all other SQL statements?

The descriptions I've read on *Max vCPU* are not entirely clear. [This one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Overview.MaxCPU.html) speaks of *number of processes*, which sounds a bit like the number of active sessions, i.e. it would apply to all wait states those sessions are in, not just CPU:

> One process can run on a vCPU at a time. If the number of processes exceed the number of vCPUs, the processes start queuing. When the queuing increase, the performance is impacted.

However the same link also states:

> If the DB load is often above the Max vCPU line, and **the primary wait state is CPU, the CPU is overloaded**. In this case, you might want to throttle connections to the instance, tune any SQL queries with a high CPU load, or consider a larger instance class.

So this seems to say *Max vCPU* only applies to the *CPU* wait state.

Is there any unequivocal corroboration for this?

Comment: For MySQL performance issues, I look primarily at the slowlog.  It gives info that is much closer to "actionable" than hardware monitoring.  In particular, "high CPU" is usually fixed via better indexing and/or reformulating the 'worst' queries.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames - I will see if the slow query log can help. However in my chart, "high CPU" does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: @RickJames Fyi, Aurora's Performance Insights use the "MySQL Performance Schema", so this is not (hardware) monitoring from the outside. So it does show the individual SQL statements and their performance data, although I have cropped that from the image, because the generic "COMMIT" comes as the unquestionable leader in the "Top SQL" list.

Comment: Yeah, "Commit" is a nuisance.  It probably refers to all the ACID stuff that gets cleaned up after the real work is finished.  I take it to "mean" that a lot of rows were locked and/or modified, and I should look for simplifying the processing.

Comment: @RickJames Hm. Only very few rows per are inserted and updated per commit. And [the docs for redo_log_flush](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/ams-waits.io-auredologflush.html) - which is the top wait state, reads: `The io/aurora_redo_log_flush event occurs when a session is writing persistent data to Amazon Aurora storage.` So I would not expect locking to be the big problem here...

Comment: I think Aurora makes 6 copies of every disk block.  I think it does not come back with an ACK until 4 of them have finished writing.  That may be slowing down I/O.  But it is ultra secure.

Comment: @RickJames You are right about the [number of copies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-the-aurora-storage-engine/): `After at least four of the six storage nodes acknowledge receipt, the write is considered successful, and acknowledgement is returned to the client application.`